# Import users from json file in keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to import functionality for users in keycloak. But in the import, I only found import clients, realm roles and client roles. Can't we import users in the keycloak? Can we do it programmatically? Please anyone help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add version of keycloak you are using .

Comment: You are able to do everything you can do using the admin UI also programatically, using the API.

Comment: I am using keycloak-authz-client of version 2.0.0.Final and keycloak-admin-client of version 2.3.0.CR1